# Cursor replacements for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I have 2 scenarios I need to replace cursors with a set operation instead.

I need to know if anyone has any ideas on this. I'm having trouble.

1. I have a table that holds the names of triggers and the table it's related to. I need to disable or enable them and currently it's using a cursor to loop through and call the

   ```
   disable trigger 

   enable trigger
   ```

   Is there a way to call these passing a set of data?
2. I have a temp table being inserted into like
   A cursor is used to hold a set of data and a @name is pulled out row by row.

   ```
   insert into @Tmp(name)
   exec usp_here @name, @value  -- this returns a single column
   ```

-- Update --
I pulled the query out of the stored procedure and used a CTE instead of a cursor and joined directly to it. This was one option. Are there any others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this whole process run as a job or run from one command?

Would it be ok to run one command to setup a second step?

If so, you could do something like this:

To Enable:

```
select 'enable trigger ' + [the trigger name] + ' on ' + [the object name]
from [your table]
where [how you identify the triggers]
```

-or-

To Disable:

```
select 'disable trigger ' + [the trigger name] + ' on ' + [the object name]
from [your table]
where [how you identify the triggers]
```

These will give you a list of all the commands needed to enable or disable the triggers. You could output this to a sql file or copy and paste the output to a new query windows and then run it.

Comment: It's inside a stored procedure right now, running row by row to enable or disable.  but I'm trying to make it more set based.

Comment: I did this along with a sp_executesql to execute the commands.